# How to check the value returned by function is correct?

Tags: python, data-structures

I am trying to write function which remove and returns the last item from the linked list.
The code is successfully removing the last time, but I am not sure whether it is returning the correct item.

I have tried printing the current
print(current)

```
return current
```

returns the last node

```
mylist.pop()
print(current)
```

Throws the error: current is not defined

if I print

```
print(mylist.pop())
```

Output:

```
<__main__.Node object at 0x000001EB42303CD0>
```

My Code:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, initdata):
        self.data = initdata
        self.next = None

    def getData(self):
        return self.data

    def getNext(self):
        return self.next

    def setData(self,newdata):
        self.data = newdata

    def setNext(self,newnext):
        self.next = newnext

class UnorderedList:

    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None

    def __str__(self):
        res = ''
        temp = self.head
        while temp:
            res += str(temp.data) + " "
            temp = temp.next
        return  res[:-1]

    def pop(self):
        print(f'Original Linked List: {self}')
        current = self.head
        previous = None
        while current.getNext() != None:
            previous = current
            current = current.getNext()
        print('Popped item is: %d' % (current.data))
        previous.setNext(current.getNext())
        print(f'New Linked List after pop: {self}')
        return current
```

Comment: Google 'unit test'. There's a practice around testing software like this.

Comment: Google `type hints python`

Comment: It isn't supposed to be a `Node` object?

Comment: But you have the line: `print('Popped item is: %d' % (current.data))`. Surely this tells you what is returned from the `pop()` method?

Answer (score 0):

`print(mylist.pop())` is correct, you just need to better understand what the printed message means. Try implementing `__str__` or `__repr__` in your `Node` class, it will be clearer.